# Runtime error when I use goroutines to capture packets from multiple interfaces device using "github.com/google/gopacket/pcap"

Tags: go, goroutine, gopacket

I want to capture packets on 4 interfaces devices eth0, eth1, eth2, and eth3 by using "github.com/google/gopacket/pcap" . The machine I am using have large number of traffic. Lets say it is in lacks per minute. I used goroutines to capture packets on each device parallely.

I get one of following error after some time (after 1 hour less or more) when I run my binary of code on centOS 7 machine.

> 1) runtime: pointer 0xc441198b80 to unallocated span idx=0x108cc
>   span.base()=0xc441196000 span.limit=0xc441197ff0 span.state=3 fatal
>   error: found bad pointer in Go heap (incorrect use of unsafe or cgo?)
>
> 2) Segmentation fault
>
> 3) fatal error: systemstack called from unexpected goroutine
>   Segmentation fault

How I am using goroutines-

```
func main(){
             done = make(chan bool)
             var status bool = true
             for _, interface_device := range util.ConfigDetails.InterfaceDeviceList{
                   go func(device string) {           
                       status = CapturePackets(device)
                       fmt.Println("status is", status)
                       done <- true
                }(interface_device)
              }
             // wait for all goroutines to complete before exiting
               for _ = range util.ConfigDetails.InterfaceDeviceList {
                 <-done
               }

    }

    func CapturePackets(device string) bool {

       handle, err = pcap.OpenLive(device, snapshot_len, promiscuous, pcap.BlockForever)
        if err != nil {
            util.Log.Errorf("%v",err)
        }

        defer handle.Close()

        packetSource := gopacket.NewPacketSource(handle, handle.LinkType())
        parser := gopacket.NewDecodingLayerParser(
                layers.LayerTypeEthernet,
                &ethLayer,
                &ipLayer,
                &ip6Layer,
                &tcpLayer,
                &udpLayer,
                &payload,
            )
    for packet := range packetSource.Packets() {
     foundLayerTypes := []gopacket.LayerType{}
     var ip_source,ip_dest net.IP

            for _, layerType := range foundLayerTypes {

                if layerType == layers.LayerTypeIPv4 {
                    ip_source = ipLayer.SrcIP
                    ip_dest = ipLayer.DstIP
                }

                if layerType == layers.LayerTypeIPv6 {
                    ip_source = ip6Layer.SrcIP
                    ip_dest = ip6Layer.DstIP
                }
          fmt.Println(ip_source)
          fmt.Println(ip_dest)
      }
    }
 return true
    }
```

Please do help me.

Comment: Did you fix your issue?